# Can't run FacePreview on android device

Tags: android, eclipse, javacv

When you attempt to run the sample javacv 1.1 FacePreview (https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/FacePreview.java) from eclipse error message:

```
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606): Process: org.opencv.samples.facedetect, PID: 26606
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/Loader;
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FaceView.<init>(FdActivity.java:125)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity.onCreate(FdActivity.java:98)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    ... 15 more
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):        ... 16 more
12-22 21:54:10.439: E/AndroidRuntime(26606):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I did everything according to instructions https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv
tell me what could be the problem?
sorry for my English.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you as\dd all the mentioned jars?

Comment: Which install instructions did you follow? Maven, Gradle, or manual?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood you, but I did everything according to instructions, added "properties-> Java build path-> libraries" all libraries .jar from folder javacv-bin